# How do I find "Global-Global Layout" to change its name?

Tags: page-layout, package

Trying to install a package in my sandbox, but it keeps giving me the following error:

> The name "Global-Global Layout" is already used on component type: Page Layout. Please rename existing component.

I've looked around but I can't find how to get to the 'Global' page layout. I googled it and tried looking at Global Actions but nothing there allowed me to fix the error.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: A good search engine for salesforce related items is http://findsf.info/

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why your package is updating that. I would assume the package would provide their own layouts. Maybe worth contacting the publisher to make them aware of this error that many more clients will receive when installing on Summer '14.

Anyway, you can update the name of the Global Layout like this (on a Summer '14 instance):

1. Go to Setup->Create->Global Actions->Publisher Actions
2. Click on 'Edit' next to the Global Layout
3. Click on 'Layout Properties' at the top
4. Update the name and click on 'save'

Comment: We're migrating EVERYTHING from a developer account to a blank sandbox (with custom fields, layouts, list views, everything deleted). And on my sandbox, Global Actions does not have a sub-menu, and Publisher Actions isn't on the page when I click on Global Actions.

Comment: So you can edit the package then? Why not manually remove this layout from the package? Is your developer account on Summer '14 and your Sandbox on Spring '14? That might trigger more probs..

Comment: It is but I don't think we're using any new features. I'll just delete from package.

Answer (score 0):

The name conflict is due to the Global Layout in Salesforce1:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook/Content/salesforce1_global_actions_2.htm

You can deploy to Global-Global Layout but only with Salesforce1 related customizations.  Here's the example we use in our project:
https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Cumulus/blob/dev/unpackaged/post/first/layouts/Global-Global%20Layout.layout